# Mysql connect without username/password

Tags: php, mysql

I build a new website for a client (WordPress is underlying) and have access trough FTP to his webspace. He does not provide or even know more informations than this because he had taken it from an former employee.

Is it possible to get know if any MySQL database exist on localhost and connect to it without the knowledge of an username or password?

I dont think that the web space host could help me with this problem, because they switched there business orientation a while ago and don't provide any new web space at all.

Comment: I think you're going to need a user name. And whether a password is needed will depend upon how the user is setup. This is a bit of an odd question because if you *should* have access to it, then you *should* have a user name available to you to use. And such access isn't generally available through FTP. MySQL access is generally through port 3306 using a MySQL client.

Comment: The problem is, that the client really don't know anything at all of his own webspace (configuration, access, and so on). So all I have is this FTP user and a bunch of user/pass combinations without assignment to specific services. Also the webspace host couldn't help me, cause the changed their business structure a while ago and do not provide new webspaces...

Comment: By *client* I am referring to the application you would need to access the MySQL server. If you have potential candidates for user name and password, then I'd suggest installing a MySQL client program (or use command line) and connect to the server normally through port 3306 and try different combinations until you hit one. I assume by "a bunch" it can't be too onerous a task unless you have 100's of each. If you use command line, and you're clever, you could probably write a script that would try them all for you.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible to attempt to connect to a database without knowing the username, password, or whether it even exists.

If you could have someone log into MySQL (requires admin privileges without the MySQL name/password) they could run `mysql> show databases;` at the MySQL command line interface to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have access to the server root, you should be able to find the config file for Wordpress. It will contain the address, database name, username and password for the MySQL server.
Note that you might only be able to connect to it via a localhost, but PHPMyAdmin should help you out with that.